wordcloud2 for R: other htmlwidget graphs don't show when wordcloud is included
I'm creating a Quarto html-document for my students and want to use different interactive charts, including a wordcloud. However, if I include the wordcloud the other charts don't show in the document. I have latest version of wordcloud2 (and everything else as well since I had to reinstall recently).
Update:
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt) -- "Puppy Cup"
No particular error messages. Just that when I uncomment the Wordcloud the highcharter graph doesn't show. See result here.
Example:

    ---
    title: "Title"
    author:
      name: A. Thor
    format:
      html:
        embed-resources: true
    editor: visual
    ---
    
    # Title1
    
    Wordcloud here
    
    ```{r}
    #| echo: false
    #| message: false
    #| warning: false
    
    library(wordcloud2)
    
    # IF I UNCOMMENT THIS THE NEXT GRAPH WILL NOT SHOW!
    #wordcloud2(data=demoFreq, size=1.6)
    ```
    
    # Title2
    
    blah blah
    
    ```{r}
    #| echo: false
    #| message: false
    #| warning: false
    
    library(tidyr)
    FV.df <- data.frame(T = seq(1:26)-1)
    FV.df$FV5s <- 1+0.05*FV.df[,1]
    FV.df$FV5 <- (1+0.05)**FV.df[,1]
    FV.df$FV10 <- (1+0.1)**FV.df[,1]
    FV <- gather(FV.df, "Rate", "FV", -T)
    
    ```
    
    ```{r}
    #| label: fig-FV
    #| fig-cap: "Fremtidsverdien oeker rentenivaa og hvor lenge den forrentes. F.eks: 1 krone investert i dag vil om 20 aar, hvis renten er 10%, ha vokst til 6,72 kroner. Vi kan ogsaa se at det tar litt over 7 aar for at 1 krone dobles hvis renten er 10%."
    #| echo: false 
    #| message: false
    
    library(highcharter)
    
    cols <- c("#004178","#cfaf70","#00aaff" )
    
    hc <- highchart() %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "Enkel rente (5%)", type="line", FV.df, mapping = hcaes(x = T, y = FV5s)) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "5%", FV.df, type="line", mapping = hcaes(x = T, y = FV5)) %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "10%", FV.df, type="line", mapping = hcaes(x = T, y = FV10)) %>% 
      hc_colors(cols) %>%
      hc_title(
        text = "<b>Fremtidsverdi av én kontantstrøm i dag.</b>",
        margin = 20,
        align = "left"
        ) %>%
      hc_subtitle(
        text = "Tre forskjellige renter, og opp til 25 ars horisont",
        align = "left"
      ) 
    
      hc
    
    ```



Do you get any error message that you can share?

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What version of R are you using?

Now updated to R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt) -- "Puppy Cup". Same problem. No error messages.

I found the following solution at Github-page for Wordcloud2 (by "jazzic", link):

    ```{r}
    #| echo: false
    #| message: false
    #| warning: false
    
    library(wordcloud2)
    library(htmlwidgets)
    
    # IF I UNCOMMENT THIS THE NEXT GRAPH WILL NOT SHOW!
    a <- wordcloud2(data=demoFreq, size=1.6)
     
    htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = a,
                            file = "a.html",
                            selfcontained = TRUE)
    
    ```
    
    <iframe src = "a.html" width = "1000" height = "1000"></iframe>


Replacing my wordcloud code chunck above, and the iframe produce this file which is exactly what I want.
